# Anchor to portion of table

Tags: html

I need an anchor to a portion of an HTML table.

I have the following code that is in a page called Speakers.html:

```
       <tr>
         <a name="MatLink"></a>
         <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#0177C0" class="tableheading"><div align="left">Phil Mat</div></td>
       </tr>
```

From another page I have the following:

```
    <h3><a href="Speakers.html#MatLink">Phil Mat</a></h3>
```

when I click on the above link, it does not go to the designated area. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give `id` attribute to your link

```
<a id="MatLink" name="MatLink"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks Felix. But when I click on the link it goes to the top of the Speakers page but not at the middle. I added your suggestion